# Creating a matrix of solutions from an ODE

Tags: matlab, ode

R0range is a 1xK vector. If R0range is only one variable you get a Tx3 matrix for phi where T is time. I want to output phi as a Tx3K matrix, so for every value of R0range.

```
function phi = solveODE( t, phi0, N, k, R0range )
 for n = 1:length(R0range)
     [t, phi] = ode45(@(t, phi) modelSIR(t, phi, N, k, R0(n)), t', phi0);
 end  
end
```

Right now if you input
`phi = solveODE ( [3;5;7;9;11] , [2 ,4 ,6] , 10 , 0.3 , [0.5 ,1.5] )`
you only get the answer for 1.5. Namely:

```
phi =

    2.0000    4.0000    6.0000
    1.4941    2.5619    7.9439
    1.2435    1.5884    9.1681
    1.1108    0.9686    9.9207
    1.0372    0.5853   10.3775
```

Comment: You need to actually assemble the list of solutions. So start with an empty list and append each solution. Or use array processing via `arrayfun(@(R)solveODE( t, phi0, N, k, R),R0range)`, where `solveODE` is reduced to a single solution.

Comment: The fist one worked! Thanks!